# Prestashop add to cart function

Tags: php, module, prestashop, cart

I have to make a prestashop module in which I have to change the total from the cart with the one that I am calculating (depending on width and height of the product). 
I am calculating the new price on an ajax.php file inside my module, save the price into a custom table from my database, and then from inside the Product.php I read that values in order to get the new price.
But I am stucked at the point of adding the new value in the actual basket. What method should I call ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every price of any product in the shop is generated through `Product::getPriceStatic()`. Including cart prices. In the database there are prices only in the product's table. In the cart there are called various methods to get prices, but essentially, it is making a query to get product IDs for a cart ID, then join it with product's table, to their prices and calculate them through `getPriceStatic`.

You do not say, how you are calculating a new price, or rather when. When a product is added (in admin)? When a product is added to a cart?

I would advise you to override the method getPriceStatic in such a way, that if your product has a record in your custom table, you implement some code that recalculate the product's price.